# Adjust margins in persp/persp3d in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, margins

Long-time reader; first-time poster here.  I am posting because I am trying to create multi-panel 3-dimensional plots with custom axes, and I cannot seem to do it without cutting off the axis labels.

More specifically, I am trying to create a plot using `persp3D()` in the `plot3D` package.  It's a function that uses `persp()`.  It's easy to set `persp(..., axes = F)` to turn off the axes.  From there, like `persp()`, I can use `trans3d()` to add lines, text, etc., as shown elsewhere (for example, [link](http://entrenchant.blogspot.co.id/2014/03/custom-tick-labels-in-r-perspective.html)).  Adding the axes and axis labels works just fine, but I cannot figure out how to increase the margins to accommodate the axis labels I am adding to the plot.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
# fake data
test.mat <- matrix(runif(100)*1:10, nrow = 10)

# describe axis parameters
x.axis <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .1)
min.x <- min(x.axis); max.x <- max(x.axis)
y.axis <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by = .1)
min.y <- min(y.axis); max.y <- max(y.axis)
z.axis <- pretty(seq(from = min(test.mat), to = max(test.mat), by = 0.1))
min.z <- min(z.axis); max.z <- max(z.axis)

# 3d plot without axes
pmatt <- persp(test.mat, box = F, theta = 35, axes = F, xaxs = "i")

# just a little function for plotting the axes
bbox <- function(min.x, max.x, min.y, max.y, min.z, max.z, pmat, ...){
    lines(trans3d(min.x, min.y, c(min.z, max.z), pmat), ...)
    lines(trans3d(min.x, max.y, c(min.z, max.z), pmat), ...)
    lines(trans3d(max.x, max.y, c(min.z, max.z), pmat), ...)
    lines(trans3d(c(min.x, max.x), max.y, max.z, pmat), ...)
    lines(trans3d(min.x, c(min.y, max.y), max.z, pmat), ...)
}

# print axes
bbox(min.x, max.x, min.y, max.y, min.z, max.z, pmat = pmatt)

# create ticks and labels, and place them with trans3d
tick.start <- trans3d(x.axis, min.y, min.z, pmatt)
tick.end <- trans3d(x.axis, (min.y - 0.10), min.z, pmatt)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)
label.pos <- trans3d(x.axis[], (min.y - 0.15), min.z, pmatt)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels = c(x.axis), adj = c(1, 0.95), srt = 0, cex = 1)

tick.start <- trans3d(max.x, y.axis, min.z, pmatt)
tick.end <- trans3d((max.x + 0.1), y.axis, min.z, pmatt)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)
label.pos <- trans3d((max.x + 0.15), y.axis, min.z, pmatt)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels = c(x.axis), adj = c(0, 0.95), srt = 0, cex = 1)

tick.start <- trans3d(min.x, min.y, z.axis, pmatt)
tick.end <- trans3d(min.x, (min.y - 0.1), z.axis, pmatt)
segments(tick.start$x, tick.start$y, tick.end$x, tick.end$y)
label.pos <- trans3d((min.x - 0.15), min.y, z.axis[-1], pmatt)
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels = z.axis[-1], adj = c(1.5, NA), srt = 0, cex = 1)
```

And, in all, the labels are cutoff by the margin.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I can tell, no matter the size or dimensions of the graphics device window, the z-axis (vertical axis) will be cut off.  That's the one I'm going for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question while searching for an answer to the same problem.  In the end I solved it by adding the parameter `xpd = T` into the calls for `text()`.  E.g,

```
text(label.pos$x, label.pos$y, labels = c(x.axis), adj = c(1, 0.95), srt = 0, cex = 1, xpd = T)
```

This extends the labels for the entire length of the x axis rather than cutting it off.